# warning about strlen() on BYTE type

Tags: c, string, char, strlen, unsigned-char

I am trying to compute the hash value of some words using sha256, but when I use sha256_update() function,

```
typedef unsigned char BYTE;
BYTE text1[] = {"abcd"};
sha256_update(&ctx, text1, strlen(text1));
```

use strlen() on BYTE type will give me some warnings, so I want to know what is the proper way to get the length of the text1?

```
In file included from /usr/include/memory.h:29:0,
             from sha256-test.c:16:
/usr/include/string.h:384:15: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘BYTE {aka unsigned char}’
 extern size_t strlen (const char *__s)
           ^~~~~~
sha256-test.c:54:36: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 1 of ‘strlen’ differ in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]
  sha256_update(&ctx, text1, strlen(text1));
```

Comment: `text1` is an array of strings, it should be `strlen(text1[0])`.

Comment: Cast the argument to `(const char *)`

Comment: @Barmar that's a different thing :P

Comment: I wonder why the error message says that the argument is of type `BYTE` rather than `BYTE *`.

Comment: @Barmar ah, it is about *text2*. But the initializer is "ok" though weird for an *array*.

Comment: Please show the actual code causing the error. The error message seems to relate to code like `BYTE text2 = "abcd";` without `[]` after the variable name.,

Comment: Why are you using the `BYTE` type instead of `char`?

Comment: Post the real code, not something you cooked up just for SO.

Comment: Please [edit]  your question, your code doesn't match the warning message. Read carefully comments number 4 and 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the typedef name `BYTE` is defined the following way

```
typedef unsigned char BYTE;
```

In this case cast the type `unsigned char *` to type `char *` (or to `const char *` ) because there is no implicit conversion between the types. For example

```
BYTE text1[] = {"abcd"};
sha256_update(&ctx, text1, strlen( ( char * )text1 ) );
```

Take into account that for such initialization of the array

```
BYTE text1[] = {"abcd"};
```

(when the size of an array is determinated by its initialization with a string) you can get the length of the string also the following way

```
sizeof( text1 ) - 1
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned char BYTE;

int main( void )
{
    BYTE text1[] = {"abcd"};
    size_t n = strlen( ( char * )text1 );

    printf( "n = %zu\n", n );
    printf( "sizeof( text1 ) - 1 = %zu\n", sizeof( text1 ) - 1 );
}
```

Its output is

```
n = 4
sizeof( text1 ) - 1 = 4
```